# typescript multiple generic cannot infered properly

Tags: typescript, generics, union

In vscode with typescript

multiple generic not infered properly when to use User-Defined Type Guards

```
const arraySample = [1, [3, 4], ["s"]];

const isFlat = <T, U>(array: (T | T[] | U | U[])[]): array is (T | U)[] => {
  return !array.some(Array.isArray);
};

if (isFlat(arraySample)) {
  arraySample;
}
```

vscode tooltip say below with error:

`const isFlat: <number, number>(array: (number | number[])[]) => array is number[]`

but I think it must be

`const isFlat: <number, string>(array: (number | number[] | string | string[])[]) => array is (number|string)[]`

could you let me know the proper solution?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can't really infer anything meaningful for `U` in your code, since it won't know where to split up a union.  Instead, since [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) were introduced I'd tend to do it the other way... just let `T` be the element type of the array and pull out array types from it in the type guard.  Like this:

```
const isFlat = <T>(array: T[]): array is Exclude<T, any[]>[] => {
    return !array.some(Array.isArray);
};

const arr = ["a", 2, true, Math.random() < 0.5 ? "d" : ["d"]];
if (isFlat(arr)) {
    arr; // (string | number | boolean)[]
} else {
    arr; // (string | number | boolean | string[])[]
}
```

Does that work?  Hope that helps; good luck!